# Wordpress get page_id=2 as first page that comes up, not blog

Tags: wordpress, redirect

So I have decided to enter in the wonderful world of wordpress, it all seems pretty simple and straight forward.

My only problem is when people goto my site they go here....

http://jamessuske.com/taran/ the blog page.

My question is how do I get my users to goto this page http://jamessuske.com/taran/?page_id=2 when they go to http://jamessuske.com/taran/

I hope this makes sense...but thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by going to Settings -> reading settings -> check A static page (select below) -> select your page in the dropdown.